# Object reference not set to an instance of an object Message with String Array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StarBusModel.BookingDetail1 objBooking = new StarBusModel.BookingDetail1();
    objBooking.TourID = tourID;
    objBooking.Name = txtName.Text;
    objBooking.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
    objBooking.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form[txtAmount.ClientID]);


    string []  seats = Request.Form[txtSeatNo.ClientID].Split(new char[] {','});
    for (int i = 0; i < seats.Length; i++)
            objBooking.SeatDetails.Add(new StarBusModel.SeatDetail1() {SeatID = Convert.ToInt32(seats[i])});
    objEntities.BookingDetail1.AddObject(objBooking);        
    objEntities.SaveChanges();
    BindSeats();
}
```

I get the error

`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

at the following code:

```
string []  seats = Request.Form[txtSeatNo.ClientID].Split(new char[] {','});
```

Please advise where I am wrong. I searched for various answers but cannot pinpoint where I am wrong.

Comment: this `Request.Form[txtSeatNo.ClientID]` may give you `null`???

Comment: it is always good to perform a sanity check on your input form value before any manipulation. By the way, why you need to split the txtSeatNo ?

Comment: Why can't you access txtAmount.Text and txtSeatNo.Text? Why you need to get control values using form collection??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Request.Form[txtSeatNo.ClientID]` is clearly null. In general, a `NameValueCollection` (like `Request.Form`) will return a null string if the given key is not defined.

You should do a check:

```
string seatString = Request.Form[txtSeatNo.ClientID];
string [] seats = String.IsNullOrEmpty(seatString) ? new char[]{} :
     seatString.Split(new char[] {','});
```

Comment: This helped me trace back the code and solve the null value returning for Request.Form[txtSeatNo.ClientID]. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

NullReferenceException is a very headache excpetion. Even though you can know the line where the exception happen by see the stacktrace. But it may also include more than 1 possibilities.

Your case is an example.

```
string []  seats = Request.Form[txtSeatNo.ClientID].Split(new char[] {','});
```

In fact in this line, there are 2 place can cause null exception. They are:

1. txtSeatNo.ClientID
2. Request.Form[txtSeatNo.ClientID]

Normally the second is most possible.

So it is better to write the code in multiple lines and check the value before you use it. I think Jacob Abrahams gave a very good example.